# How to set custom headers in all methods of a Symfony 4 Controller with FOSRestBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, http, symfony4

I'm building a RESTFUL API with FOSRest Bundle and return data with custom headers like this:

```
class InvestorController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{

    /**
     * Retrieve a list of investors
     *
     * @Rest\Get("/{page}", defaults={"page"=1}, requirements={"page"="\d+"})
     *
     * @param Integer $page
     * @param Request $request
     * @param InvestorRepository $investorRepository
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getInvestorsAction($page, Request $request, InvestorRepository $investorRepository)
    {
        $data = $investorRepository->getInvestorsList($page);
        $data = $this->getUser()->getId();

        $view = $this->view($data, 200)
                     ->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000') // Remove this bit in PROD
                     ->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); // Remove this bit in PROD


        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to pass these headers for all of the responses in this Controller. I would like to avoid having to send them manually each time. Is there a way to set custom headers for all of the controller's responses automatically, say, in the constructor or in somewhere else?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways how to do this:

1. First one that comes to my mind would be to configure your webserver to attach these headers to every response it sends based on URL.
2. Second one would be to utilize Symfony internal event system and catch `kernel.response` and attach the headers there. You would need to filter the response based on where is coming from - 
   https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-response
3. The other thing would be to create your own custom handler which calls these `setHeader()` methods instead of doing it inside Controller. To provide this handler you can simply override `handleView()` method -
   https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html#custom-handler